# Get pmrep on jenkins running on Linux

Tags: jenkins, informatica-powercenter

How do i get the PMREP working on the linux Jenkins server? 
Do i have to install  informatica powercenter client for Linux? is there one available?

I am trying to setup a Linux Jenkins server. So that i can execute the `pmrep` commands for deployment remotely. i have the shell scripts and they can be executed on the server locally. I think the utility `pmrep` is installed as a part of the client development tools for Informatica.

Comment: Yes - at least as far as I know, pmrep is part of the client tools.

Answer (score 0):

okay - so looks like there is a "command Line client" available just for this. The command line utilities comes as a part of the client installation as well as a server installation. And there is no client tools viz: repository manager, designer, workflow manager, monitor for a unix/linux environment. So, in such a situation where you don't want to install the whole server package, just to get the command line utilities (on a linux server); one have to get this `"command Line client"` and set it up in your linux box.   Check out this [thread](https://network.informatica.com/thread/61956?sr=inbox&ru=2035) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You just need an Informatica commandline utilities, no install required. Just copy the commandline utility folder from your Informatica server (or contact Informatica admin) to Linux